# RDP client logs (history of connections from local PC to any remote servers)

Tags: rdp, log-files, windows-10, history

is there a log file in Win10 where i can find all history of connected RDP sessions from machine? Example: on my local computer i connect to different remote servers and i need history of all login actions of this. All i need it's IP of remote server with which i connected and username (domain login or local login) with dates.

I readed about winlogs in TerminalServices-LocalSessionManager or RemoteConnectionManager but there is no informations about my remote connections. Also is there a way to check active connection (netstat on rdp port) but here i have only machine IP.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, there are the event logs. Just parse them for what you need or configure a filter.